# continuity entropy with respect gibbs measures

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, probability-distributions, fractals, symbolic-dynamics

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. For simplicity I consider Bernoulli measures on $X$ only.

Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be Holder continuous.  The measure $\mu$ is a **Gibbs measure** with potential $f$ if there are $C>0$ and $P\in\mathbb{R}$, such that for every infinite sequence $i_1 i_2\ldots$ and all natural $n$,
$$
C^{-1} \le \frac{\mu[i_1\ldots i_n]}{\exp(-nP+f(i)+f(\sigma i)+\cdots+f(\sigma^{n-1}i))} \le C,
$$
where $\sigma$ is the one side shift.

we write $h(\mu)$ for the Kolmogorov-Sinai (metric) entropy of $\mu$.

$$Question$$
 Consider a topology on the Gibbs measures via the Holder topology on the potentials.Why is $h(\mu)$ continuous with respect to this topology?

**comment** we know that entropy is upper semi continuous,thus we have to show that why $h(\mu)$ is lower semi continuous.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the Bernoulli measure?

Comment: See my paper with Zaqueu Coelho. We show that the Gibbs measure depends d-bar continuously on the potential; and entropy is continuous with respect to d-bar distance.

Comment: The link is http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/aquas/papers/paper05.pdf

Comment: @RW i want to work measure of maximal entropy and in case Bernoulli,we can easily write $H(\mu)=-\sum p_{i} log p_{i}$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, professor @AnthonyQuas

Comment: @AnthonyQuas,I have one more question, I have seen the question as a remark of a paper by Hasselblatt and schmeling(2004),they did not mentioned your paper(because that was before your paper),i am really curious,can we prove it with out your paper?I totally understand your paper , i just want to know ,is there another way for proof?

Comment: My paper preceded that of Hasselblatt and Schmeling. Unfortunately I am unable to find the book chapter where their paper Dimension product structure of hyperbolic sets appears. I could not see the question you mention in the AMS Research Announcement.

Comment: I sent paper to you.

Comment: @ Michal Measure of maximal entropy for what? One can figure out without much effort what you wanted to ask (whether the dependence of a Gibbs measure on its potential is continuous) - but this is by far not what you wrote.

Comment: @RW, ok,you are right,never mind Bernoulli,do you know why entropy is continuous with respect to that topology?because i still dont know.

Comment: Is $X$ a full shift?  Is $\mu$ shift-invariant?

Comment: @Algernon No,i just edited my question. $\mu$ is Bernoulli measure,thus is shift-invariant

Comment: What is the topology on Gibbs measure via the Holder topology on potentials?  You mean the weak* topology?

Comment: @Algernon yes,it is weak* topology

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots$ and $\mu$ be invariant measures and $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ and $f$ be continuous functions such that

1. $f_n\to f$ uniformly,
2. $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly,
3. $\mu_n$ is an equilibrium measure for $f_n$, that is, $h(\mu_n)-\mu_n(f_n)=p(f_n)$, where $p(g):=\sup_\nu[h(\nu)-\nu(g)]$ is the topological pressure of $g$.  [Recall: an invariant Gibbs measure for a Hölder function $g$ is an equilibrium measure for $g$.]
4. $\mu$ is an equilibrium measure for $f$. [This in fact follows from the previous three conditions.]

The topological pressure is continuous, thus, $p(f_n)\to p(f)$, that is,
\begin{align}
   h(\mu_n) - \mu_n(f_n) &\to h(\mu)-\mu(f) \;.
\end{align}
On the other hand, $\mu_n(f_n)\to\mu(f)$ because
\begin{align}
   |\mu(f)-\mu_n(f_n)| &\leq |\mu(f)-\mu_n(f)| + |\mu_n(f)-\mu_n(f_n)|
\end{align}
and both terms on the righthand side go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  It follows that $h(\mu_n)\to h(\mu)$.

This doesn't quite answer your question (if I understand it correctly) because of the assumption $f_n\to f$.

Comment: Yes,i don't assume continuity potential.

Comment: If you take a look the paper,Prof.Quas mentioned who proved it, we have continuity potential,as well.I am wondering ,is there another way for proof it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "continuity potential".  Do you mean the assumption $f_n\to f$?

Comment: yes. I mean exactly that one.

Comment: But from what I understand from Anthony's comment and paper, his argument shows something else: it shows that if $f_n\to f$, $\mu_n$ is Gibbs for $f_n$, and $\mu$ is Gibbs for $f$, then $h(\mu_n)\to h(\mu)$.  Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: Let me check again Anthony's paper.I am interested to  prove the continuity of the map from potentials to Gibbs states with respect to the Holder topology on potentials and weak* topology on measures

Comment: one more things about your proof,how do you know topological pressure is continuous?

Comment: Because i dont remember any result about continuity of topological pressure.

Comment: The continuity of the map from potentials to invariant Gibbs measures follows from the uniqueness of invariant Gibbs measures and the fact that an invariant Gibbs measure for Hölder potential $g$ is one and the same thing as the equilibrium measure for $g$.

Comment: The Lipschitz continuity of topological pressure (w.r.t. the uniform topology) is standard (e.g., Theorem 3.4 of Ruelle's book). With the variational definition of the topological pressure I used above, the proof is pretty simple: take two continuous functions $f$ and $g$.  If $\mu$ is an equilibrium measure for $f$, we get $p(f)=h(\mu)-\mu(f)$ and $p(g)\geq h(\mu)-\mu(g)$, which gives $p(f)-p(g)\leq\mu(g-f)\leq||f-g||$ and by symmetry $p(g)-p(f)\leq||f-g||$.  Hence, $|p(f)-p(g)|\leq||f-g||$.